# Base table or view not found error

Tags: laravel, database-migration

ProductTable

```js
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->integer('size');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

When I hit submit, I got error saying base table not found

[image]

Comment: Based on your controller code, I can say you passes the view name `Success` may be the wrong given.

If this is not working solution, Provide your model + validation(if performed) detail for deep digging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel can not find the prular form of the table name that you used, just specify your table name on your model like so; And check your view aswell make sure on your resource/view you have a file named successs.blade.php

```
public $table = "yourTableName";
```

Comment: @DanielAsyraf :) please mark as an answer and vote up thank you

Answer (score 0):

may be your table is not available in database so first add the table in 
    your database. in your model like this

```
public $table = "yourTableName";
```

after the define your table in your model just migrate the table in your database

```
php artisan make:migration
```